# Error [WinError 87] when installing Kivy on Windows 7

Tags: python, kivy, virtualenv

I'm following the instructions here https://saas1907y5.saas-secure.com/projects/pitanga-square/wiki on a computer running Windows 7.

When I have to execute `py -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I tried reinstalling Python 3.6.5 and it didn't solve.
Also, when I run the next command `py -m virtualenv env` I get another error:

```
RuntimeError: failed to query D:\pitanga-v21.08 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'
```

My guess was that there was something wrong with the permissions Python has, so I opened the folder properties -> security and gave full control to everything, that didn't fix it. Instead I got another error:

```
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

For the record, I tried following the same steps on a Windows Vista machine I have here and (even though it's not officially supported) it worked fine.

Comment: By any chance are you using comodo internet security?

Comment: No. I have seen people with similar problems and that seemed to be the reason, but that's not my case.